# Set default editor to use with 'gem open'

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How to save the default editor in `.gemrc` so that I can skip providing the editor with the following command:

`gem open GEMNAME [-e EDITOR] [options]`

Comment: Have you tried setting `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

1) **Using a .gemrc file:**

> **GEM ENVIRONMENT**
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> The RubyGems environment can be controlled through command line
>   arguments, gemrc files, environment variables and built-in defaults.
>
> Command line argument defaults and some RubyGems defaults can be set
>   in a ~/.gemrc file for individual users and a gemrc in the SYSTEM
>   CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY for all users. These files are YAML files with
>   the following YAML keys:
>
> ```
> :sources: A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from
> :verbose: Verbosity of the gem command. false, true, and :really are the
>           levels
> :update_sources: Enable/disable automatic updating of repository metadata
> :backtrace: Print backtrace when RubyGems encounters an error
> :gempath: The paths in which to look for gems
> :disable_default_gem_server: Force specification of gem server host on push
> <gem_command>: A string containing arguments for the specified gem command
> ```

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

Note the last line. For example, if I put the following in ~/.gemrc:

```
open: -e /Users/7stud/Downloads/macvim-snapshot-74/src/MacVim/mvim
```

then the command:

```
$ gem open nokogiri
```

will open nokogiri in macvim on my system.

---

2) **Using environment variables**(per mash's comment):

> **GEM OPEN**
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> The open command opens gem in editor and changes current path
>         to gem's source directory. Editor can be specified with -e option,
>         otherwise rubygems will look for editor in $EDITOR, $VISUAL and
>         $GEM_EDITOR variables.

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/

That means if I put something like the following in .bash_profile (or .bashrc):

```
export GEM_EDITOR="/Users/7stud/Downloads/macvim-snapshot-74/src/MacVim/mvim"
```

then the command:

```
$ gem open nokogiri
```

will open nokogiri in macvim on my system.  Don't forget to open a new Terminal window or issue the command:

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

to load the changes you made to the environment variables in .bash_profile.